# ¿Stack Overflow en español se está convirtiendo en el Rincón del Vago?

Tags: discusión, revisión-de-pregunta, trabajo-escolar

No llevo mucho en Stack Overflow en español, pero sí me he dado cuenta que últimamente las preguntas de la estructura abajo indicada, están aumentando mucho.

- Enunciado: En el que explica o plantea un problema.
- Métodos o trozos de código que implementar. "*Utilizar la clase* `Scanner`"
- Cómo debe ser el formato de salida.

En resumen, ejercicios de aprendizaje de programación....

Ya que esta es una comunidad, me parece perfecto que nos ayudemos entre nosotros y compartamos nuestros conocimientos. Pero sinceramente, como programador *junior* estoy totalmente en desacuerdo con esta práctica, ya que en realidad al alumno solo le estamos ayudando a aprobar/entregar los ejercicios. Porque lo único que aprende es a ser un maestro del `Ctrl C` + `Ctrl V`.

Como no se que podemos o no podemos hacer para solventar el problema, no hago una pregunta en sí, sino que prefiero que digáis vuestras opiniones y posibles soluciones a estas cosas.

> Sé que está la opción de cerrar la pregunta, pero creo que se podría hacer algo diferente

PD: Para los estudiantes que publican aquí los "deberes" solo os diré que los profesores también usan Stack Overflow ;)

Aclaración: No sé si el "Rincón del Vago" es una web solo conocida en España, pero por si acaso lo explico: es una web donde estudiantes publican sus deberes/trabajos/resúmenes y el resto tiene acceso a ellos.

---

Esta ha sido la pregunta "[detonante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35671/juego-de-pensador-y-adivino)", pero ha habido muchas mas. Y como dice [Pablo Claus](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1090/stackoverflowes-se-est%C3%A1-convirtiendo-en-el-rinc%C3%B3n-del-vago#comment2715_1090) me parece perfecto ayudar a alguien si muestra el código que ha hecho y hace una pregunta concreta, pero no un ejercicio entero.

Comment: Aclaración: No se si el "Rincón del Vago" es una web solo conocida en España, pero por si acaso lo explico: Una web, donde estudiantes publican sus deberes/trabajos/resúmenes y el resto tiene acceso a ellos.

Comment: Yo recuerdo haber usado el rincón del vago en la universidad, hace ya 10 años atrás. No sé si también estaba online cuando estaba en el colegio, la que sí recuerdo es www.monografias.com que me "ayudaba" con mis trabajos. Solo como sugerencia, te pediría que coloques al menos un par de ejemplos de estas preguntas que indicas, me parece que este tema ya se ha cubierto antes, pero para asegurarme sería bueno corroborar esto con ejemplos.

Comment: No creo que se esté convirtiendo en el Rincón del Vago, pero sí que creo que las preguntas del tipo "Hazme el ejercicio!" son más comunes de lo que me gustaría.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza tal como dices he añadido una pregunta, aunque se que hay mas pero ahora desde el móvil no puedo buscar preguntas anteriores porque los datos me van fatal...

Comment: La idea sería ayudar en un caso puntual. Pero si le hacemos el ejercicio, estaríamos atentando contra el objetivo del trabajo práctico.

Comment: @rencinas La verdad todos los días veo a alguien que pregunta cosas que no se deben y dan ganas de mandarlos al ****, pero para mi parecer deberían ser mas estrictos, yo estoy en stackoverflow desde que empezó siendo una comunidad inglesa, he hecho preguntas en la comunidad inglesa en un principio y me han borrado preguntas por solo el hecho de que lo que preguntaba no pertenecía al estándar de dicho lenguaje, y eso que la pregunta estaba bien redactada, ahora uno pregunta algo como: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35598/arreglos-unidimensionales-en-c y no pasa nada.

Comment: Si se incluye el código con fallos no veo problema en decirle donde está el error y ayudarle a salir del problema y si no hay código responder una "forma de como resolverlo" y no todo hecho es la forma que creo correcta.

Más que eso es buscarle la quinta pata al gato a mi parecer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Según dice la [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) de SO Español

No son pertinentes:

> Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo.

Por lo que si nos encontraríamos con alguna pregunta para resolver un trabajo práctico con solo el enunciado, sin muestras de trabajo por parte del OP, deberíamos votar por el cierre.

Answer (score 7):

No estoy muy familiarizado con el sitio web Rincón del vago, pero coincido en que algunas preguntas en Stack Overflow en Español son del tipo:

*Tengo X problema, ¿cómo lo resuelvo?* o *¡Hazme el ejercicio!* *

<sub>* tal como indica el usuario PaperBirdMaster en su [comentario.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1090/stackoverflowes-se-est%C3%A1-convirtiendo-en-el-rinc%C3%B3n-del-vago?cb=1#comment2693_1090)</sub>

Esta situación también se presenta en otros sitios de Stack Exchange, como Stack Overflow (en inglés).

Allí, *en Stack Overflow en inglés* cuando yo encuentro preguntas de baja calidad *(y si es un usuario que no ha visitado el tour, es decir, un nuevo usuario)*, coloco el siguiente comentario:

> [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please explain what you tried...add some code, show examples and explain the problem. 
>   This is not a code request forum. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for learn how you can improve your question.

Hacer esto en Stack Overflow en Español creo que puede **afectar a cómo los nuevos usuarios perciben** a la comunidad de Stack Overflow en Español, pero tampoco podemos permitir que el sitio permita preguntas de baja calidad; pero, por otro lado, puede que esta sea **la manera mas directa de decirle a un nuevo usuario** que debe esforzarse un poco mas para que su respuesta sea aceptada por la comunidad que está dispuesta a ayudarle.

Si la pregunta definitivamente no puede salvarse *con ediciones, votos, etc*, ésta debe ser eliminada.

Comment: Hice mención de [¡Hazme el ejercicio!](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/588/preguntas-de-hacedme-el-ejercicio-que-me-han-mandado) porque precisamente era el título de una pregunta de esta temática que formulé hace tiempo :)

Answer (score 3):

Igualmente aun asi le hagas el ejercicio de nada sirve, porque cuando toque el momento de trabajar de verdad tendra que resolver problemas por si solo, y sino aprende, dura un mes y listo...