# Uso indebido del sitio

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Hoy han aparecido unas cuantas preguntas que me hacen suponer que algunos estudiantes están usando el sitio para copiar, he observado un par de preguntas (dejo [link1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/519955/combobox-binding-source-xml) y [link2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/519964/combobox-xaml-binding) aunque eliminadas y [link3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/519969/en-xaml-alguien-sabe-como-crear-un-collection-view-source-con-xml-data-provide)) que eran básicamente un copia y pega de código con varias respuestas con posibles soluciones. Esta última no está eliminada dado que "*cumple*" las normas del sitio, pero me ha levantado la duda:

> ¿Es correcto permitir preguntas que levanten sospechas sobre malas prácticas de estudiantes?

Estas sospechas que tengo son porque son preguntas no muy elaboradas, de fácil resolución y por usuarios recién registrados, aparte se ve que se ha autorespondido:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una opción de reporte que tenemos es para los que intentan que les hagan los deberes, pero este es un caso diferente, ¿Se podría incluir? ¿Cómo se puede afrontar un uso indebido del sitio?

Comment: Si se permite, terminamos llenos de basura.

Comment: por ello la última pregunta, cómo lo afrontamos?

Comment: Si la pregunta esta bien formulada, no es duplicada, y tiene una buena respuesta, no veo ningún motivo por el que eliminarlas. No llegue a ver los primeros 2 links, pero si el 3ro es como los primeros 2, este tipo de preguntas auto respondidas pararan siendo cerradas por las mismas normas de la comunidad, no creo que haya que tenerles especial atencion.

Comment: Me preocupa que no sé molesten en editar la respuesta que ya publicaron y hagan una nueva. Hace un mes o dos había visto dos preguntas casi idénticas. No sé si se trataba de compañeros de clase o de la misma persona con otra cuenta, pero las dos preguntas estaban mal hechas.

Comment: @Pablochaches ese es el problema, esta ultima esta bien formulada, pero las dos anteriores eran copia y pega en preguntas, respuestas y comentarios, por eso fueron eliminadas, lo que me preocupa es que se use el sitio para malas prácticas de programación, no me parece correcto en convertir SOes en elrincondelvago y es por eso que escribí esto a modo de discusión sobre como afrontar esto

Comment: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1090/193460

Comment: Simplemente se cierra y que el sistema se encargue de enviarlo a las profundidades de la indexación ....

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Stack Overflow en español se está convirtiendo en el Rincón del Vago?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1090/stack-overflow-en-espa%c3%b1ol-se-est%c3%a1-convirtiendo-en-el-rinc%c3%b3n-del-vago)

Comment: vote por el cierre de esta pregunta ya que considero que @Pollo aporto una pregunta similar con el mismo objetivo y que es anterior por ende la considero un duplicado; si Nicolás puedes argumentar por que tu post es diferente podríamos considerar darle seguimiento a esta solicitud. pero creo que la solución sigue siendo la misma.